# Axios get request working locally but timing out on serverless

Tags: express, http, web-scraping, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm trying to scrape some websites, but for some reason it works locally (localhost) with express, but not when I've deployed it to lambda. Tried w/ the ff serverless-http and aws-serverless-express and serverless-express plugin. Also tried switching between axios and superagent.

Routes work fine, and after hrs of investigating, I've narrowed the problem down to the fetch/axios bit. When i don't add a timeout to axios/superagent/etc, the app just keeps running and timing out at 15/30 sec, whichever is set and get an error 50*.

```
service: scrape
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-2
  memorySize: 128
  timeout: 15
plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
  - serverless-express
functions:
  app:
    handler: src/server.handler
    events: 
      - http: 
          path: /
          method: ANY
          cors: true
      - http: 
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: ANY
          cors: true
```

```
    protected async fetchHtml(uri: string): Promise<CheerioStatic | null> {
        const htmlElement = await Axios.get(uri, { timeout: 5000 });

        if(htmlElement.status === 200) {
            const $ = Cheerio.load(htmlElement && htmlElement.data || '');
            $('script').remove();

            return $;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: How long does it take to run the api call locally? Also, have you tried running locally with the `serverless-offline` plugin? Though this should be entirely unrelated to the Serverless framework or express...

Comment: From Postman test using http://127.0.0.1:3000 It works

Comment: Every figure out what the issue was? Running into something similar now

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, the default timeout of axios is indefinite. Remember, API gateway has hard limit of 29 sec timeout.

I had the same issue recently, sometimes the timeouts are due to cold starts. So I basically had to add a retry logic for the api call in my frontend react application.

Comment: Yep, then i added a 5-10 sec timeout for axios. That's how i found out that axios/request was the problem. Which is weird considering that the request returns a proper response when tested locally, and the whole operation only takes 0.5s

Comment: do you have lot of lambdas, network latency may high if you have many lambdas it seems

Comment: i had to add a retry logic to try calling the api 3 times from my front end to tackle cold starts

Comment: I don't think it's a cold start problem, sorry forgot to mention, it works on other websites, just not on a particular one, i'm currently investigating if it has something to do with headers, or if they banned aws lambda ip or something

Comment: ok for me it was cold start, because the first order of the day was failing to execute. retry logic works pretty well as well.